# Unable to authenticate facebook using spring MVC getting invalid email

Tags: java, spring, facebook, rest, spring-mvc

i am trying to authenticate facebook using spring to make a ssl secure connection i have downloaded facebook certificate and using keytool i imported the keystore and has shown the path in below code where key store is  but i am not able to authenticate i am only getting facebook page saying invalid email address but i am using same credentials to login i am able to

my java code:

```
@Controller
public class Service{


    @RequestMapping("/hello")


     public String Data(ModelMap model) throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, FileNotFoundException, IOException, KeyManagementException, UnrecoverableKeyException{

        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream("/users/crohitk/Documents/workspace/frr/publickey1.cert"),
                "password".toCharArray());
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                new SSLContextBuilder()
                        .loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                        .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, "password".toCharArray()).build());
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory).build();
        ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(
                httpClient);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);


        ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange("https://facebook.com/login/",  HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<String>(createHeaders("email", "password")), String.class);



        model.addAttribute("message", result);

        return "helloworld";


      }


     HttpHeaders createHeaders( String username, String password ){
        HttpHeaders header =  new HttpHeaders();
        String auth = username + ":" + password;
        byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(auth.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")) );
        String base64Creds = "Basic " + new String( encodedAuth );
        header.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);
        return header;
    }   


}
```

web.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">


    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher.xml file :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="frr.frr" />


    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: please check if there is any thing wrong in xml files

Comment: i think you need to check your `createHeaders` method, remove "Basic " from your `base64Creds` string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change encoding credentials of above code to below code in java file there is some error in encoding of above code

```
HttpHeaders createHeaders(){
    String plainCreds = "user:password";
    byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
    byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);
    String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);


    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);
    return headers;
}
```